# BigQuery sorting floats

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, floating-point, language-lawyer

In BigQuery it gives [the following](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#orderable_floating_points) for how it sorts float:

> **Ordering floating points** 
> Floating point values are sorted in this order, from least to greatest:
>
> 1. NULL
> 2. NaN — All NaN values are considered equal when sorting.
> 3. -inf
> 4. Negative numbers
> 5. 0 or -0 — All zero values are considered equal when sorting.
> 6. Positive numbers
> 7. +inf

I can confirm this with something like this query:

```
with floats as (
  select 1.2 val union all select -1.2 union all select cast('-Infinity' as float64) union all select null
  union all select +0.0 union all select -0.0 union all select cast('+infinity' as float64) union all select cast('nan' as float64)
) select * from floats order by val
```

[image]

However, when doing a direct comparison between two float values, it doesn't always follow that. For example:

```
select cast('nan' as float64) < cast('infinity' as float64)
```

Produces `false`, which is not the correct ordering. Why is this so?

Comment: The sorting operation uses a different comparison operation than `<`. It is using some operation for that is for comparing sorting order, whereas `<` is for comparing numerical values.

Comment: Very interesting question. Even `select cast('nan' as float64) <= cast('nan' as float64);` produce `false`. I believe there are some kind of deterministic rules in the implementation.

Comment: The behavior of NaN comparison is defined in IEEE-754 specs, examples include NaN < 1 -> false, NaN > 1 -> false, NaN = 1 -> false (one of them should be true for normal numbers). But then how would you sort them if you can't compare? The answer is to make an exception for sort operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a peculiar behavior of floating point values, and is not limited to BigQuery but is a standard behavior as defined by IEEE 754 floating point standard. This standard specifies that any comparison with NaN is unordered. In other words, NaN is not less than, greater than, equal to, or not equal to any number, including NaN itself.

So when you compare NaN to Infinity or any other number, the result is false because NaN is not less than Infinity, but also not equal or greater than.

However, when it comes to sorting, the behavior is defined differently. BigQuery, like many systems, will put NaN values before -Infinity but after NULL values. This is an arbitrary choice and is done to ensure consistent sorting behavior. This might not seem to align with the concept of NaN being unordered, but it allows you to sort data that may contain NaN values without running into problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer is good, but add a bit of context/references, and I'll award the bounty to you.

Answer (score 2):

`NaN` is not a number, not sure why you would expect your comparison to be true.  A "non-number" is *not* less than any numerical quantity.  Similarly, `=`, and `>` also return false.  Interestingly, `<>` and `!=` *do* result in a `true` value, as a "non-number" definitely does not equal a number.

Per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#comparison_operator_examples): `Comparison operators provide standard IEEE-754 behavior for floating point input.`
Per [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) (or at least it's representation on wikipedia): `Any comparison with a NaN is treated as unordered.`